# How to convert points between two coordinate systems with different rotations

Tags: math, unity-game-engine, trigonometry

Imagine two coordinate systems layed on top of each other, with a rotation and scale difference between the two:

[image: Example]

The problem is to convert a point from the non-rotated system to the other. What we do have, are four corner points forming a rectangle, with coordinates known for both systems at each point. We also know the rotation difference, and I think I at least should know the scale difference too. How do I convert a point from the non-rotated system to the rotated system? I have Unity3D at use.

Extra points for clarity in math :)

PS: I'm writing this really late, going to edit later for more clarity.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Some linear algebra does the trick:

Express each operation as a matrix and [matrix multiply](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Matrix_multiplication) those to combine them into a single resulting matrix (for efficiency).

If translation is involved you need to add a dimension to your matrices, see [homogenous coordinates](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Translation_%28geometry%29).

The reason is that the mappings are affine ones then, not linear ones. You can ignore the extra dimension in the end result. It is just a nice way to embed affine mappings into linear ones, so the algebra is easier.

Example

```
M = M_trans * M_rot * M_scale
x' = M x
```

The order here is right to left: vector x is first scaled, then rotated, then translated into vector x'. (Using column vectors).

Hints on the matrices: [Rotation Matrix](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Matrix_rotation), [Scaling Matrix](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scaling_matrix)

For deriving 2D formulas when given 3D ones: either keep z = 0 or delete the 3rd row and 3rd column from each matrix.